# sql count rows where diff Dates is less than 30 minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, date, compare

```
PersistentId     UserId      EnterDate
111              1           June 1, 2015 17:05
112              1           June 1, 2015 17:21
113              1           June 1, 2015 17:27
114              1           June 1, 2015 18:25
115              1           June 1, 2015 19:00
116              2           June 1, 2015 18:05
117              2           June 1, 2015 18:21
118              2           June 1, 2015 19:27
```

I'd like to get a list of UserIds and a count for each UserId such that only rows where the difference between EnterDates < 30 minutes are included.

So for the above data, the output would be

```
UserId        Count
1             3
2             2
```

The rows that should be pulled for UserId 1 are with persistentIds 111, 114, 115.

The rows that should be pulled for UserId 2 are with persistentIds 116, 118

Any ideas on how I can write this SQL query?

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Comment: Would `17:05`, `17:30` and `17:55` be a count of 2 or 3? There is a difference of less than 30 minutes between subsequent pairs but a difference of 50 minutes between first and last. What happens if you have `19:00`, `19:25`, `20:00` and `20:25`? Is the `UserID` given twice as there are two periods with the less than 30 minutes between them or is the count 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two queries that both give your expected results and use 30 minute windows but have completely different interpretations of your requirements... you might want to clarify the question.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f765/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (PersistentId, UserId, EnterDate ) AS
          SELECT 111, 1,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:05','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 112, 1,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:21','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 113, 1,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:27','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 114, 1,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:25','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 115, 1,  to_date('June 1, 2015 19:00','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 116, 2,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:05','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 117, 2,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:21','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 118, 2,  to_date('June 1, 2015 19:27','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1 - Count results in 30 minute windows**:

```
SELECT UserId,
       "Count"
FROM (
  SELECT UserID,
         COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EnterDate RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30' MINUTE PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS "Count",
         EnterDate,
         LEAD(EnterDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EnterDate ) AS nextEnterDate
  FROM   Table_Name
)
WHERE "Count" > 1
AND   EnterDate + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE < nextEnterDate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f765/7/0)**:

```
| USERID | Count |
|--------|-------|
|      1 |     3 |
|      2 |     2 |
```

**Query 2 - Count all rows that are within 30 minutes of another row**:

```
SELECT UserID,
       COUNT(1) AS "Count"
FROM (
  SELECT UserID,
         EnterDate,
         LAG(EnterDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EnterDate ) AS prevDate,
         LEAD(EnterDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EnterDate ) AS nextDate
  FROM   Table_Name
)
WHERE  EnterDate - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE < prevDate
OR     EnterDate + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE > nextDate
GROUP BY UserId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f765/7/1)**:

```
| USERID | Count |
|--------|-------|
|      1 |     3 |
|      2 |     2 |
```

Comment: My apologies.  I didn't phrase the question correctly.   Firstly a correction, I'm only interersted in rows where the difference between enterDates > 30 minutes.  From the original example,  it would give a count of 3 for userId 1 b/c it would pull the records with persistentId  111, 114, 115.  The enterDate difference between 111 and 114 is over 30 minutes and so also between 114 and 115.

Comment: Based on the provided solutions, I think this will work:   'SELECT UserID,
       COUNT(1) AS "Count"      
FROM (
  SELECT persistentid,
        UserID,
         EnterDate,
         LAG(EnterDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EnterDate ) AS prevDate,
         LEAD(EnterDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EnterDate ) AS nextDate
  FROM   Table_Name
)
WHERE  EnterDate + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE < nextDate
or nextDate is null
GROUP BY UserId'

Comment: @tsc - That query gives the expected result for that data but for other data it will not work. See the two queries in this [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31136/2) - I have commented out the row with `persistentId` of 117 and there are zero rows within 30 minutes of another for that `UserId` however your query (the second one) shows a count of one (which it will always do with the `nextDate IS NULL` clause).

Comment: @MTO - if I'm interested in rows where the time difference is  **>** 30 minutes, then the query works.  If there is only 1 entry, then the nextDate will be null and I need to add that to the count.

Comment: @tsc - The text of the question states `EnterDates < 30 minutes` and you're now saying `time difference is > 30 minutes` - forgive me if I'm confused...

Comment: @tsc - for Time differences greater than 30 minutes ( or singular rows) I'd do something like [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f765/9) - which effectively negates the where clause in query 2 (above).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't worded clearly, but based on your desired results, I think you want to use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out records that are less than 30 minutes after another record with the same user id.  Like this:

```
with d as ( 
SELECT 111 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:05','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') enter_date from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 112 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:21','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 113 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:27','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 114 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:25','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 115 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 19:00','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 116 persistent_id, 2 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:05','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 117 persistent_id, 2 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:21','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 118 persistent_id, 2 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 19:27','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual
)
select d.user_id, count(*)
from d
where not exists ( SELECT 'record for same userid but less than 30 minutes earlier'
                   FROM   d d2
                   WHERE  d2.user_id = d.user_id
                   AND    d2.enter_date between d.enter_date - (0.5/24) and d.enter_date 
                   and    d2.persistent_id != d.persistent_id )
group by d.user_id                   
order by d.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [LAG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) function to get prev. enterDate for the user and calculate duration between events

```
select user_id, count(*)
from
(with d as ( 
SELECT 111 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:05','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') enter_date from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 112 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:21','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 113 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 17:27','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 114 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:25','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 115 persistent_id, 1 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 19:00','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 116 persistent_id, 2 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:05','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 117 persistent_id, 2 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 18:21','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 118 persistent_id, 2 user_id,  to_date('June 1, 2015 19:27','Month DD, YYYY HH24:MI') from dual
)
select d.user_id, persistent_id, enter_date
,lag(persistent_id) over (partition by user_id  order by enter_date)
,lag(enter_date) over (partition by user_id  order by enter_date)
,(enter_date - nvl (lag(enter_date) over (partition by user_id  order by enter_date), enter_date))*24*60 duration
from d
) where duration < 30
group by user_id

--results
    USER_ID COUNT(*)
1   1   3
2   2   2
```